# Remove external drive from Time Machine

Tags: time-machine, external-disk

I bought an external drive several months ago but I haven't used it heavily until now. I discovered today that I forgot to exclude it from Time Machine, and so when I started adding tons of files to it today Time Machine complained that it didn't have enough space to back up.

I excluded the external drive, and it still won't backup. When I look in the Backup.backupdb file, I can see the folder for the external drive, but I can't remove it.

How can I recover that space so it can back up my main drive again?

[image]

Comment: Possibly https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22905/cant-delete-old-time-machine-backups

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer from an on-line friend.

> The procedure varies with different versions of macOS but it should be
>   something like this:
>
> There's a little gear icon you can have visible in Finder windows. 
>   You need this.  So if you have customised the toolbar to remove it,
>   put it back in.  You also need the Time Machine icon in your menu bar,
>   and to connect your backup drive if it's not already connected.
>
> Open a Finder window and pilot your way to a view which shows the
>   volume you want to remove.
>
> Use the Time Machine menu bar icon --> Enter Time Machine
>
> In that Finder Window highlight the volume / files you want to remove.
>
> From the gear icon at the top of that window choose "Delete all
>   backups"

I did that and now instead of 294.41GB available on my TimeMachine drive, I have 3.74TB.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an option on Big Sur